# angular2 app with authentication login page

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular

`<navigation title="dashboard" has-header="true" >
    <auth-router-outlet></auth-router-outlet>
</navigation>`

I'm working on a angular2 app with authentication. I have a navigation toolbar shared between all the page except login page. But with the configuration above the login page will have the navigation toolbar. Not sure what is a better way to implement this, which seems common in most apps.
Thanks!

navigation is a component I created with navbar on top.
auth-router-outlet extends angular's default router-outlet with authentication and redirect to login page if not authenticated.

Comment: can you just hide it in CSS or something?

Comment: yeah. I can use ng-if in angular to hide it when not logged in. But I feel like this is kind of hack. not sure what is a better approach.

Comment: You can also use routing to show different components depending on the logged-in state. If you need global services it's currently a bit hacky https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112 but I expect that to get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ngIf` is not a hack for me since the toolbar will be removed from the DOM when the login page is rendered and not only hided.